# Command takes too long to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code for this, I admit is not great however I have been testing for a couple of days now and I cannot seem to improve it.

Basically I am using the module `systeminformation`: [Docs](https://systeminformation.io/)

My issue currently is that when running my command, it takes on average 7 seconds to complete and send the embed, I am sending the complete code in the hopes of the reader having a better understanding of what is happening.
When I first wrote the code, none of the data from `systeminformation` was under await, this caused the bot to crash due to it trying to send the embed before it gets the information.

````js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const si = require('systeminformation');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'stats',
        usage: '${prefix}stats',
        category: 'informative',
        description: 'Displays stats about the bot',
        accessableby: 'Everyone',
    },
    run: async (bot, message) => {

        console.time() // Just a way for me to check how long it takes to complete
        function convertMS(ms) {
            let d, h, m, s;
            s = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
            m = Math.floor(s / 60);
            s = s % 60;
            h = Math.floor(m / 60);
            m = m % 60;
            d = Math.floor(h / 24);
            h = h % 24;
            return {
                d: d,
                h: h,
                m: m,
                s: s,
            };
        }

        const u = convertMS(bot.uptime);
        const uptime =
            u.d +
            ' days, ' +
            u.h +
            ' hours, ' +
            u.m +
            ' minutes, ' +
            u.s +
            ' seconds';

        const msg = await message.channel.send('Generating...');
        message.channel.startTyping();
        let ping = Math.round(bot.ws.ping);
        await si.mem().then(data => totalMemory = Math.floor(data.total / 1024 / 1024));
        await si.mem().then(data => swapMem = Math.floor(data.swapused / 1024 / 1024));
        await si.mem().then(data => cachedMem = Math.floor(data.cached / 1024 / 1024));
        await si.mem().then(data => memoryUsed = Math.floor(data.used / 1024 / 1024));
        let realMemUsed = Math.floor(cachedMem - swapMem + memoryUsed);
        let memPercent = Math.floor(realMemUsed / totalMemory * 100);
        await si.currentLoad().then(data => cpuUsage = Math.floor(data.currentload_user));
        await si.osInfo().then(data => osVersion = data.distro);
        await si.versions().then(data => nodeVersion = data.node);

        msg.delete();
        const serverembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor('Ragnarok Info', bot.user.avatarURL())
            .setFooter(`Bot Created • November 4, 2018`)
            .setColor('#7289DA')
            .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL())
            .addFields({
                name: 'Owner',
                value: 'Ragnar Lothbrok#1948',
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Uptime',
                value: uptime
            }, {
                name: 'Memory Usage',
                value: `${realMemUsed} / ${totalMemory} - ${memPercent}%`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'CPU Usage',
                value: `${cpuUsage}%`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Ping',
                value: `${ping}ms`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Users',
                value: bot.users.cache.size,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Versions',
                value: `OS: ${osVersion}\nNode.js: ${nodeVersion}\nDiscord.js: v12`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Guilds',
                value: bot.guilds.cache.size,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: 'Announcements',
                value: '```N/A```',
            });
        message.channel.send(serverembed);
        message.channel.stopTyping();

        console.timeEnd() // Just a way for me to check how long it takes to complete

    },
};
````

Comment: Don't forget to ask an explicit question.  You'll know you've done it because one of your sentences will end with a question mark.  :)  Your issue is that it takes 7 seconds and the bot crashes.  What do you need to know from us?

Comment: First thing I notice at a glance is that you call `si.mem()` repeatedly.  Why not just call it once and stash the results?

Comment: Perhaps you could increase the granularity of the timing...time multiple sections..see what piece of it is taking all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it's taking so much time to complete is because you are waiting for each of the promises to resolve before continuing. It would be worth storing the result of `si.mem()` and then taking the values from there.

```js
const memory = await si.mem();
const totalMemory = Math.floor(memory.total / 1024 / 1024);
const swapMem = Math.floor(memory.swapused / 1024 / 1024);
const cachedMem = Math.floor(memory.cached / 1024 / 1024);
const memoryUsed = Math.floor(memory.used / 1024 / 1024);
```

Another improvement would be to cache the results of `si.osInfo()` and `si.versions()`. Because these will not change during the runtime of your progam.